# How to mount volume in jenkins 2.361

Tags: jenkins, volume

In old jenkins like 2.263, we used to pass volumes in docker template like below which used to work:
/usr/local/accurev:/usr/local/AccuRev

Here I am installing new jenkins 2.361, and in place of volume, there is option of mount for passing volumes , i am not getting how to pass volumes here. i have given

source=/usr/local/accurev,target=/usr/local/AccuRev

But jenkins complain
jenkins: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.BadRequestException: Status 400: {"message":"create /usr/local/accurev: "/usr/local/accurev" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path"}

The mount instruction says: New line separated list of host mounts : New line separated list of host mounts : type=volume|bind|tmpfs|npipe[,src|source=],dst|destination|target=[,=]*

Can anyone help me how to pass volume with this version of jenkins. As i am not getting how to share volumes with this new version.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
type=bind,source=/usr/local/accurev,target=/usr/local/AccuRev
```

The default type is a Docker Volume, which doesn't allow forward slashes.